# Function works properly without passing parameter to another function?

Tags: c, function

How does this code work properly? I use a function to insert an array and another function to print that array in the console but I didn't passed the array to the function to print the array but it works fine. What is the reason for that?

**program**

```
void getArray();
void DisplayArray();

int main(void)
{
    getArray();
    DisplayArray();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getArray()
{
    int limit, b[10];
    printf("Enter the limit:");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    printf("Enter the values of the array:");

    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
}

void DisplayArray()
{
    int i, n, array[10];
    printf("The values of Array is: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter the limit:4
Enter the values of the array2
4
6
8
The values of Array is:
2
6
8
```

Comment: You're *unlucky* that it works. The contents of the array `array` inside the `DisplayArray` function is really *indeterminate*.

Comment: Besides, `int limit, b[10],1;`? That shouldn't build. Please make sure that you ***copy-paste*** your [mre] into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not *work*, it has undefined behavior.  The function `getArray` reads the numbers into a local array and the function `DisplayArray` prints the contents of a local array that is uninitialized, with index value running from `0` up to `n`, which is also uninitialized (!).  It seems to behave as expected because both arrays happen to be allocated at the same address at runtime, but you cannot rely on this. The behavior is just undefined.

Indeed, you'll see that not both outputs **are not** exactly the same.

Here is a modified version with defined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getArray(int *array, int n);
void DisplayArray(const int *array, int n);

int main(void) {
    int limit, b[10];

    printf("Enter the limit: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &limit) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (limit < 1 || limit > 10) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid limit: %d\n", limit);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    getArray(b, limit);
    DisplayArray(b, limit);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getArray(int *array, int n) {
    printf("Enter the %d values of the array:\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void DisplayArray(const int *array, int n) {
    printf("The values of Array are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
void DisplayArray()
{
    int i, n, array[10];
    printf("The values of Array is: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", array[i]);
    }
}
```

the variable `array` is unitialized. When you read an uninitialized variable, the behavior of your program is undefined. That means it can do absolutely anything. If you call another function between these two, for example, the output changes.

Always initialize your variables.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work. It is called undefined behaviour as you use uninitialized array `array` in the function `DisplayArray`.

You see the numbers be incident because the new stack allocated `array` was located at the same place in memory as the array `b`.

But it doesn't mean that your program is working. It is just a coincidence.